# Vagrant in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, vagrant

I need to know what is vagrant ,how it is helping in hadoop development environment,i hear that vagrant provides a virtual environment for hadoop cluster,can anyone tell me how it is useful for hadoop administration ,with the help of  it can we able to create a hadoop cloudera  manager cluster using simple 8 gb windows laptop to practise hadoop administration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant can be used in providing local VM environments for different software stacks and operating systems of your choosing to help with development work, testing software out, sandpit environments and much more. In your case, yes, you could use vagrant to assist in practising with hadoop. The use of Vagrant is not just for hadoop however and as such I would advise firstly spending some time reading up and getting familiar with what vagrant is and how it works.

Here are some links that you might find useful:

- https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/why-vagrant/
- https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/
- http://hackr.io/tutorials/vagrant

There is a [blog posting](http://dandydev.net/blog/installing-virtual-hadoop-cluster#.VqYe0FOLRHQ) that shows the use of vagrant and hadoop. However, I would not dive straight into this until you have spent more time learning about vagrant.